# PyQt6 Error: Could not parse stylesheet of object, when running packaged app packaged with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, qtstylesheets, pyqt6

I'm building a GUI for a personal project. I designed the GUI using Figma and downloaded my custom images as an svg. I then used these svg's as the background-images for the widgets in my app. I do this by setting the StyleSheet of each widget with it's corresponding image as followed:

`self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(" + background_path + ");}")`

where the background_path is:

`os.path.join(base_directory,"Images","Figma","login_window","Background.svg")`.

I set the base directory using the following if statements:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    EXE_APPLICATION = True
elif __file__:
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    EXE_APPLICATION = False
```

The app is working perfectly when I run it from my IDE, but when I package the application using pyinstaller, none of the images are loaded and I receive the following message from the terminal `Could not parse stylesheet of object`. The line of code I'm using to package my app using pyinstaller is

`pyinstaller --windowed --name="Scouting Tool" --icon="colina_icon.icns" --add-data="Data:Data" --add-data="Fonts:Fonts" --add-data="Images:Images" cst_0.1.py`.

The Data, Fonts, and Images folders are located in the same directory as my python file. When I look into the `dist` folder all three folders are present with all of the images and information present in them. I added a print statement to make sure the path was correct when the app is packaged and it looks correct to me:

`/Users/wapym/Desktop/Colina_GUI/dist/Scouting Tool/Images/Figma/login_window/Background.svg`.

I am not sure why when the app is packaged it can't parse through the styleSheet, but when I run it from my IDE it can. I'm not sure if this is a PyQt6 issue or a pyinstaller one. I've tried looking into Qt resources, but they seem to have been deemed obsolete for PyQt6. I also tried using pngs, but I get the same error. If anyone knows why this issue is happening please let me know. :)

Comment: The real question is: even if path looks correct, does the file actually exist in that path?

Comment: @musicamante if I follow the path from the dist folder, the image files are there.

Comment: Ensure that the url is always put inside quotes: `self.setStyleSheet("... url('" + background_path + "');}")` (note the single quotes before and after the double quotes used as string delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @musicamante, the solution is adding line delimiters around the url.

`self.setStyleSheet("... url('" + background_path + "');}")`